# Path as String returning incorrect value (in Windows)

Tags: python

```
mypath = 'H:\Desktop\2020\pythonWork'
print mypath
```

This returns:

```
H:\Desktop‚0\pythonWork
```

Ran using the Python IDLE 2.7

Must be something simple, right?
What am I not seeing?

Comment: I think we need more information?

Comment: Store your string as a `raw string` - `mypath = r'H:\Desktop\2020\pythonWork'`

Comment: Support for python 2.7 ended https://pythonclock.org/  Please upgrade.  Once the interpreter is upgraded to the latest, you can use pathlib.Path('H:\Desktop\2020\pythonWork')

Comment: Upgrading to the newest Python is not an option. The office is running its entire solution in 2.7. So I have to be compliant to 2.7, not the other way around.

Comment: For future reference, you can see the issue when you call `mypath` in idle without print. It was returning; `'H:\\Desktop\x820\\pythonWork'`. `\x` is a hex escape char, so you were printing `\x82` which in hex is a square.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @PacketLoss

```
mypath = r'H:\Desktop\2020\pythonWork'
```

This produced the correct output.

Regards.